# Base Href and Angular Routing and Views

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm developing a web application which defines the `<base href="phoenix/">` in the header as explained [in this article](http://www.verdantrefuge.com/writing/2013/angularjs-changing-app-path-base-element/).

The default URL that is mapped is `http://localhost/phoenix/` however even when defining the base tag in the header my views and routes are not being redirected correct.

I enabled HTML5 routing:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

and then defined my route like:

```
app.config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/login', {
        templateUrl: '/views/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    });
}]);
```

It tries to resolve it as:

```
 GET http://localhost/views/login.html 404 (Not Found)
```

It works correctly if I append the base url to the `/phoenix/login` paths.  Should I have to append that via a variable I set or something or am I missing something and this should work.  Also, is this going to work on say IE8 with the header attribute base?

Comment: First guess is to remove the / from  'views/login.html'.

Comment: wow I feel like an idiot.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: No problem, ran into the same issue some time ago and it took me quite some time to figure out. AngularJS is great but sometimes pain to do work with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing the slash from the views

```
app.config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
       controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    });
}]);
```

and making links like:

```
 <a href="login">Login</a>
```

but leaving the slash for the route resolved the problem.