# Having trouble w/ AngularJS links in html5Mode and IE8

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8

I am setting up my first AngularJS app, and having a problem with links in IE8 using hashbang in html5Mode. There's one main view with data specific to a date range, with links to other date ranges within the page.
I set it up as follows:

- html5Mode is on
- I'm using ng-href to get each link from a function
- the root of the app is not at site root
- I have a `<base>` tag on the page for the app root (`<base href="/my/app/"/>`)

The page is working fine on first load in modern browsers and IE8 (necessary, sorry), and IE8's URL is transformed from `"/my/app/my/first/page"` to `"/my/app/#/my/first/page` as expected. The problem is that links aren't behaving consistently between the old and new browsers.

If I start from `"my/first/page"` and create a link to `"my/next/page"`, it looks and behaves great on modern browsers, but IE8 goes to `"/my/app/#/my/first/page/my/next/page` as if Angular isn't treating it as an in-app link. It just appends the link to the current address.

If I create the link as `"/my/next/page"` with the leading slash, IE8 does work fine but the modern browsers are treating it as absolute and outside of the app, which is expected but not desired.

If I use a valid absolute link (`"/my/app/my/next/page"`), IE8 goes to `"/my/app/#/my/app/my/next/page"`.

I can work around it by changing the location in an `ng-click`, but I'd prefer the links to look and behave like normal links for opening in separate tabs, etc.

**Update**
After working on this awhile longer, I think it might be related to an issue IE has with the `<base>` tag. Some articles have suggested using the FQDN in the base or [using javascript to fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926197/html-base-tag-and-local-folder-path-with-internet-explorer), but neither of those have had an effect.

Comment: what version or angular?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Base Href and Angular Routing and Views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19939685/base-href-and-angular-routing-and-views)